# Cannot deserialize json data

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I cannot deserialized the following data which I'm using for testing and got it from the [World Bank](http://api.worldbank.org/countries/IRL/indicators/SP.DYN.CBRT.IN?per_page=10&date=1960:2016&format=json) using the following query:

```
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/IRL/indicators/SP.DYN.CBRT.IN?
per_page=10&date=1960:2016&format=json
```

```
[
  {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 28,
    "per_page": "2",
    "total": 56
  },
  [
    {
      "indicator": {
        "id": "SP.DYN.CBRT.IN",
        "value": "Birth rate, crude (per 1,000 people)"
      },
      "country": {
        "id": "IE",
        "value": "Ireland"
      },
      "value": "21.2",
      "decimal": "0",
      "date": "1961"
    },
    {
      "indicator": {
        "id": "SP.DYN.CBRT.IN",
        "value": "Birth rate, crude (per 1,000 people)"
      },
      "country": {
        "id": "IE",
        "value": "Ireland"
      },
      "value": "21.5",
      "decimal": "0",
      "date": "1960"
    }
  ]
]
```

My main class is called PageModel is defined as such:

```
public class PageModel
{
    public PageModel()
    {
        this.List = new List<Data>();
    }

    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pages")]
    public int Pages { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("per_page")]
    public string PerPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public List<Data> List { get; set; }
}
```

The class used in the array is called Data and is defined as follows:

```
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        this.Indicator = new Indicator();
        this.Country = new Country();
    }

    [JsonProperty("indicator")]
    public Indicator Indicator { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public int Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public float Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("decimal")]
    public decimal Decimal { get; set; }

}
```

Both the Country and Indicator classes are defined as follows:

```
public class Country
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Indicator
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

My `HttpClient` call returns the data correctly but whenever I try to deserialize the data using the NewtonSoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject function:

```
PageModel pageModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PageModel>(data);
```

It returns `null`.

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried deserializing parts of the string to one class at a time for debugging? This way you might be able to locate the problem more easily.

Comment: It would look that the value, decimal and date fields are of type string, not float, decimal and date.

Comment: @RhinoDevel I did. I removed the list part of it so see if I could get the basic info from the PageModel but no good I'm afraid! Still returns null.

Comment: @TonPlooij ok, I'll try that.

Comment: @TonPlooij - Didn't work after changing the types to string. Very odd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data is in wrong format:
Change your json to this and it will work:

```
{
"page": 1,
"pages": 28,
"per_page": "2",
"total": 56,
"List":[
{
  "indicator": {
    "id": "SP.DYN.CBRT.IN",
    "value": "Birth rate, crude (per 1,000 people)"
  },
  "country": {
    "id": "IE",
    "value": "Ireland"
  },
  "value": "21.2",
  "decimal": "0",
  "date": "1961"
},
{
  "indicator": {
    "id": "SP.DYN.CBRT.IN",
    "value": "Birth rate, crude (per 1,000 people)"
  },
  "country": {
    "id": "IE",
    "value": "Ireland"
  },
  "value": "21.5",
  "decimal": "0",
  "date": "1960"
 }
]
}
```

Comment: @Satish, you are correct but why on earth would the World Bank generate such invalid JSON!!! Doesn't make sense! What a waste of time and thanks again for your help.